# Help me understand this calculus on manifolds logic

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

Looking over a proof, they include this step:

$||x+y||^2 = [x + y, x+y] =||x||^2 + 2[x,y] + ||y||^2$

I don't understand how the second step goes to the third. Obviously it's something squared, but I don't understand what exactly was sequared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using scalar distributive law:

$$[x+y,x+y]=[x,x]+[x,y]+[y,x]+[y,y]$$

and also that:

$$[x,x]=||x||^2\\
[x,y]=[y,x]$$